# SQL Results next to each other

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table, mariadb

I have a different question that is hard to explain
This is the result that i'm getting right now:

```
╔═════════╦════════╗
║    Id   ║ Saldo  ║
╠═════════╬════════╣
║    1    ║10441,91║
╠═════════╬════════╣
║    2    ║ 441,91 ║
╚═════════╩════════╝
```

And this is what I want as an result(next to each other):

```
╔═════════╦════════╗════════╗════════╗
║    Id   ║ Saldo  ║   Id   ║ Saldo  ║
╠═════════╬════════╣════════║════════║
║   1     ║10441,91║   2    ║ 441,91 ║
╚═════════╩════════╝════════╝════════╝
```

So what I want is all next to each other.

And this is the query that I used:

```
SELECT 
    o.id_shop AS id,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN (s.amount + s.shipping_cost_amount) != '' THEN o.total_paid_tax_excl - (s.amount + s.shipping_cost_amount)
        ELSE o.total_paid_tax_excl
    END) AS Shop
FROM
    expoled.ps_orders o
        LEFT JOIN
    expoled.ps_oxoquotation_quotation q ON q.idOrder = o.id_order
        LEFT JOIN
    expoled.ps_order_slip s ON s.id_order = o.id_order
WHERE
    o.current_state IN (4 , 5, 20, 23)
        AND YEAR(q.date_add) = YEAR(UTC_TIMESTAMP())
GROUP BY o.id_shop
```

What did i try:
I have tried UNION to combine the result sets but that did not work.
I can get them all under each other but not next to each other.

Comment: Add rows with ID values 4, 7 and 13 to your data, and adjust the result.

Comment: Almost any other language can do that better than SQL.

Comment: Are ID and Saldo the only columns you have in that table? Is ID unique? Why do you want the results to be returned in a single row only? Depending on how you want to process the results of that query, it might be a better idea to return a comma-separated list as the result (like if you'd want to load it into some other system, Excel or whatever)

Comment: Those are the only one as result. I have more columns in that table and id is not unique. If its possible I want a single row only.

Comment: If you would be satisfied with a single row per ID (as you said they are not unique), you could check out this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table

It might suit your needs.

Comment: Do you want to work out with mentioned two rows only ?

Answer (score 1):

Will you always have only two possible ID, 1 and 2? If so, you can remove the GROUP BY o.id_shop and create two sum columns this way:

```
SUM(CASE
    WHEN (s.amount + s.shipping_cost_amount) != '' AND o.id_shop = 1 THEN o.total_paid_tax_excl - (s.amount + s.shipping_cost_amount)
    WHEN (s.amount + s.shipping_cost_amount) = '' AND o.id_shop = 1 THEN o.total_paid_tax_excl
    ELSE 0
END) AS Shop_ID_1


SUM(CASE
    WHEN (s.amount + s.shipping_cost_amount) != '' AND o.id_shop = 2 THEN o.total_paid_tax_excl - (s.amount + s.shipping_cost_amount)
    WHEN (s.amount + s.shipping_cost_amount) = '' AND o.id_shop = 2 THEN o.total_paid_tax_excl
    ELSE 0
END) AS Shop_ID_2
```